# MySQL CONCAT Sequences

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build hierarchical data from related tables using CONCAT sequential statements in a query.

The following query works:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT('program:', p.program_pk) AS global_id,
p.program_name AS name,
NULL AS parent_global_id,
NULL AS column_to_sort_by 
FROM
program p

UNION ALL

-- institution
SELECT
CONCAT('institution:', i.institution_pk) AS global_id,
i.institution_name,
CONCAT('program:', i.program_fk) AS parent_global_id,
NULL AS column_to_sort_by 
FROM
institution i 

UNION ALL

-- institution-year
SELECT
CONCAT('institution:', y.institution_fk, ',year:', y.year_pk) AS global_id,
y.year_name,
CONCAT('institution:', y.institution_fk) AS parent_global_id,       
NULL AS column_to_sort_by  
FROM
year y

UNION ALL

-- institution-year-unit
SELECT 
CONCAT('institution:', u.institution_fk, ',year:', u.year_fk, ',unit:', u.unit_code) AS global_id,
u.unit_code,
CONCAT('institution:', u.institution_fk, ',year:', u.year_fk) AS parent_global_id,
NULL AS column_to_sort_by
FROM
unit u
```

Now I want to add another level, but not familiar enough with the format.  Something like the following, but that last set of CONCATs is incorrectly formated...

```
SELECT 
CONCAT('program:', p.program_pk) AS global_id,
p.program_name AS name,
NULL AS parent_global_id,
NULL AS column_to_sort_by 
FROM
program p

UNION ALL

-- institution
SELECT
CONCAT('institution:', i.institution_pk) AS global_id,
i.institution_name,
CONCAT('program:', i.program_fk) AS parent_global_id,
NULL AS column_to_sort_by 
FROM
institution i 

UNION ALL

-- institution-year
SELECT
CONCAT('institution:', y.institution_fk, ',year:', y.year_pk) AS global_id,
y.year_name,
CONCAT('institution:', y.institution_fk) AS parent_global_id,       
NULL AS column_to_sort_by  
FROM
year y

UNION ALL

-- institution-year-unit
SELECT 
CONCAT('institution:', u.institution_fk, ',year:', u.year_fk, ',unit:', u.unit_code) AS global_id,
u.unit_code,
CONCAT('institution:', u.institution_fk, ',year:', u.year_fk) AS parent_global_id,
NULL AS column_to_sort_by
FROM
unit u

UNION ALL

    -- institution-year-unit-unit_group
SELECT 
CONCAT('institution:', u.institution_fk, ',year:', u.year_fk, 'unit:', u2.unit_code, ',unit_group:', ug.unit_fk) AS global_id,
ug.unit_group,
CONCAT('institution:', u.institution_fk, ',year:', u.year_fk, 'unit:', u2.unit_code) AS parent_global_id,   
NULL AS column_to_sort_by
FROM 
unit_group ug
```

Schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE `program` (
 `program_pk` int(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `program_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `modified_by` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`program_pk`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `institution` (
 `institution_pk` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `institution_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `program_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `modified_by` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`institution_pk`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `year` (
 `year_pk` int(1) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `year_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `institution_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `modified_by` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`year_pk`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

    
CREATE TABLE `unit` (
 `unit_pk` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `unit_code` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
 `unit_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `points` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `year_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `institution_fk` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `modified_by` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`unit_pk`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=78 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `unit_group` (
 `unit_group_pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `unit_group` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `unit_fk` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `modified_by` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`unit_group_pk`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


INSERT INTO `unit` (`unit_pk`, `unit_code`, `unit_name`, `points`, `year_fk`, `institution_fk`, `modified`, `modified_by`) VALUES
(1, 'OPTM4101', 'Principles', 6, 5, 1, '', ''),
(2, 'OPTM4102', 'Structure ', 6, 5, 1, '', '');


INSERT INTO `unit_group` (`unit_group_pk`, `unit_group`, `type`, `unit_fk`, `modified`, `modified_by`) VALUES
(1, 'Learning Events - OPTM4101', 'learning_event', 1, '2021-07-26 05:32:25', ''),
(2, 'Learning Events - OPTM4102', 'learning_event', 2, '2021-07-26 05:32:35', ''));
```

Comment: From the last select `u.institution_fk`, `u.year_fk` and `u2.unit_code`, the table aliases `u` and `u2` are not recognized !

Comment: how should that last set of CONCATS be written?

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide the definitions for the tables?

Comment: Each subquery in UNION is absolutely independent. It cannot refer on another subquery. So create single query which receives "institution-year-unit-unit_group" **only** then UNION it.

Comment: Table schemas added

Comment: OK I will modify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By joining the *unit_group* table with the *unit* table, you'll obtain the accurate result for the final select :

```
    -- institution-year-unit-unit_group
SELECT 
CONCAT('institution:', u.institution_fk, ',year:', u.year_fk, 'unit:', u.unit_code, ',unit_group:', ug.unit_fk) AS global_id,
ug.unit_group,
CONCAT('institution:', u.institution_fk, ',year:', u.year_fk, 'unit:', u.unit_code) AS parent_global_id,   
NULL AS column_to_sort_by
FROM unit_group ug
INNER JOIN unit u on u.unit_pk = ug.unit_fk
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not getting the unit_group data showing when exporting the query results from phpMyAdmin to JSON

Comment: Must be a problem somewhere

Comment: looks like it SHOULD work as the unit_group data is in the mysql results but not related to the unit data...

Comment: I have added a link to download the full db with data to the op

Comment: External links are not acceptable see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266715/4286884,
You can edit your question and provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example as text (specially some data from tables `unit` and `unit_group` )

Comment: My query is working fine, could you also add the expected output if you think my query get wrong data ? check it here https://dbfiddle.uk/ey3qy2of